# Add execute permission to all subdirectories of the current directory

Tags: bash, scripting

How can I add execute permission to all subdirectories of the current directory for the owner, the group owner and all other users except files?

I wanted to create a script to do this but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: Are they your directories?

Answer (score 2):

You have to 1) find sub-directories from the current directory and 2) add execute permission to the item-found (which is a directory).

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod ugo=+x {} \;
```

Comment: That argument to `chmod` seems a bit wrong. It should either be `ugo+x` or `a+x`. With `=` it sets the permissions to `+x`, whatever that means.  It's further unclear why you need `sudo` for this.

Comment: In my case i did not have execute permission in the sub-directory and that's the reason for the additional sudo.

Comment: Using `chmod` is probably faster (and less to type) than `find....` but since find is also useful for lots of other things I'll +1 this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `chmod` command with the recursive option (`-R`):

```bash
chmod -R a+X
```

or

```bash
chmod -R ugo+x
```

Comment: Your second option would add execute permission not only to directories but to files too